# Is there a friendly name for this data structure?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

While working on a feature selector for a machine learning algorithm in Python, I generated a data structure with the following code:

```
# Perform set partitioning on the results
groups = []
for t in results:
    (jthName,kthName) = t
    jthGroup = -1
    kthGroup = -1

    # Just a simple list of hashes with online merging
    for idx,group in enumerate(groups):
        if jthName in group:
            jthGroup = idx
        if kthName in group:
            kthGroup = idx
    if jthGroup == kthGroup:
        if jthGroup == -1: # Implicit: "and kthGroup == -1"
            groups.append(set((jthName,kthName)))
    elif jthGroup != kthGroup:
        if kthGroup == -1:
            # Merge kthName into jthGroup
            groups[jthGroup].add(kthName)
        elif jthGroup == -1:
            # Merge jthName into kthGroup (redundant if naturally-ordered)
            groups[kthGroup].add(jthName)
        else:
            # Merge jthGroup and kthGroup, since we have a connecting pair
            merged = set()
            merged.update(groups[jthGroup])
            merged.update(groups[kthGroup])
            groups.remove(groups[jthGroup])
            groups.remove(groups[kthGroup])
            groups.append(merged)
```

Where my input, `results`, is a list of tuple{2} and `groups` is a list of set. Note that my code isn't necessarily efficient here; it's provided only for illustrative purposes.

My data structure, `groups`, has the following properties:

- For each `(jthName,kthName)`:

  - If neither element of `(jthName,kthName)` is found in any contained set, create `set((jthName,kthName))` within our list of sets.
  - If exactly one of `(jthName,kthName)` is found in one contained set, coalesce the unfound element into that set.
  - If each element of `(jthName,kthName)` is found in a different set, coalesce the two referenced sets into a single set.
- Loop invariant: `jthName` and `kthName` cannot be contained in more than one set.

My justification for this data structure is to create a flat decomposition of an unknown set of connected nodegraphs, where each unique element name is a node and each unique pair is an edge. My rationale is that my graphs are incomplete, and I require this view to select *only* the known members of each graph to feed into an algorithm that will [regressively determine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) graph connectivity and directionality of the edges (that is, the complete set of [DAGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) expressed by the data). But, I digress.

Is there a friendly name for the data structure represented by variable `groups`? If so or if not, is there a more time- or space-efficient means of performing this decomposition?

Comment: May be more appropriate on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/. I didn't post it there because this is, to my knowledge, an undergraduate level question from an undertrained theorist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something called a [Disjoint-set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

It's often used when doing Kruskal's because it allows you to do n lookups in amortized nlog*n (actually less than that) time if you implement the disjoint-set data structure with path compression.

It's pretty reasonable to implement and I think the wiki page pseudo code lends itself nicely to python. If you need more assistance, [this SO question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094985/implementing-disjoint-set-system-in-python).

If you used the disjoint-set data structure, your code would look like this:

```
for t in results:
   (jName, kName) = t

   union(jName, kName)
```